# What's the most efficient way to draw this region?

Tags: graphics, regions, filling

[image]

Viral question on YouTube. But let me start by saying the guy got it wrong. We don't do such things at the age of 11, we do this question about Year 11 (aged 14/15, 16 for some).

I want to draw the following.
[image]

Tried this

```
f1 = 10 - Sqrt[10^2 - x^2];
f2 = 5 - Sqrt[5^2 - (x - 5)^2];
f3 = 5 + Sqrt[5^2 - (x - 5)^2];
```

And

```
r00 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], Transparent, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}]}]
r0 = Plot[{f1, f2, f3}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1,   PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 10.5}, {-0.5, 10.5}}]
r1 = Plot[{f1, f2, f3}, {x, 6.25 - 1.25 Sqrt[7], 6.25 + 1.25 Sqrt[7]},    Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1,   PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 10.5}, {-0.5, 10.5}}]
r2 = Plot[{f1, f2, f3}, {x, 6.25 + 1.25 Sqrt[7], 10},   Filling -> {3 -> {2}}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1,   PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 10.5}, {-0.5, 10.5}}]

Show[{r00, r0, r1, r2}]
```

[image]

Surely there is a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
f1h = HoldForm[10 - Sqrt[10^2 - x^2]];
f1 = f1h // ReleaseHold;
f2h = HoldForm[5 - Sqrt[5^2 - (x - 5)^2]];
f2 = f2h // ReleaseHold;
f3h = HoldForm[5 + Sqrt[5^2 - (x - 5)^2]];
f3 = f3h // ReleaseHold;
```

The x values for the curve  intersections are

```
{x1, x2} = x /. Solve[f1 == #, x][[1]] & /@ {f2, f3};
```

The point coordinates for the curve  intersections are

```
{pt1, pt2} = ({#, f1 /. x -> #} // FullSimplify) & /@ {x1, x2};

reg1 = ImplicitRegion[f1 < y < 10 && x > 0, {x, y}];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[f2 < y < f3, {x, y}];

Show[
 Region[
  regDiff = RegionDifference[reg2, reg1]],
 Plot[{f1, f2, f3}, {x, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> {
    {Orange, AbsoluteThickness[4]},
    {Purple, AbsoluteThickness[4]},
    {Darker@Green, AbsoluteThickness[4]}}],
 Epilog -> {
   Text[Style[x1, 14, Bold], {x1, 2}, {0, -1}],
   Arrow[{pt1, {x1, 2}}],
   Text[Style[x2, 14, Bold], {7.75, pt2[[2]]}, {1, 0}],
   Arrow[{pt2, {7.75, pt2[[2]]}}],
   Text[Style[f1h, 14, Bold], {10, 8}, {-1, 0}],
   Text[Style[f2h, 14, Bold], {9.5, 1.5}, {-1, 0}],
   Text[Style[f3h, 14, Bold], {5, 11}],
   Red, AbsolutePointSize[7],
   Point[{pt1, pt2}]},
 Ticks -> {{5, 10}, {5, 10}},
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 14}, {-1, 12}},
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

The area of the shaded region is

```
area = Area[regDiff] // FullSimplify

(* 25/2 (Sqrt[7] + π - ArcCot[3/Sqrt[7]] - 4 ArcTan[(5 Sqrt[7])/9]) *)
```

The area relative to the smaller circle is

```
area/Area[reg2] // N

(* 0.186378 *)
```

Answer (score 10):

**One simple way to visualize complicated regions in mathematica**

```
disk1 = Region[Disk[{5, 5}, 5]]

disk2 = Region[Disk[{0, 10}, 10]]

disk3 = Region[Disk[{10, 0}, 10]]

result = Region[
  RegionUnion[RegionDifference[disk1, disk3], 
   RegionDifference[disk1, disk2]]]
```

[image]

Comment: `RegionDifference` nice function!

Comment: Anyway to smooth the "tip"?

Comment: `result = RegionPlot[
  RegionUnion[RegionDifference[disk1, disk3], 
   RegionDifference[disk1, disk2]], PlotPoints -> 100]`

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in Mathematica 11.1 and 11.2. Only starting from 11.3 does it succeed, although in 11.3 `RegionPlot` from OkkesDulgerci's comment clips the RHS of the plot. In 12.0 it works normally.

Answer (score 6):

```
RegionPlot[
  x^2 + y^2 < 25 \[And] 
 ((x - 5)^2 + (y + 5)^2 > 100 \[Or] (x + 5)^2 + (y - 5)^2 > 100),
 {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Or...

```
z[w_] := EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, w {5, -5}];
RegionPlot[
 z[0] < 5 \[And] (z[1] > 10 \[Or] z[-1] > 10),
 {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

Or...

```
z[w_] := (a = ({x, y} - 5 {w, -w})).a;
RegionPlot[
 z[0] < 25 \[And] (z[1] > 100 \[Or] z[-1] > 100), 
 {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

Or even shorter....

```
z[w_, k_] := (a = ({x, y} - 5 {w, -w})).a > 25 k;
RegionPlot[
Not[z[0, 1]] \[And] (z[1, 4] \[Or] z[-1, 4]), 
{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

I would be very impressed if someone uses fewer keystrokes than this in a `Region`-based solution:

```
d[c_, r_:10] := Region[Disk[c, r]];
RegionDifference[d[{5, 5}, 5], RegionIntersection[d[{0, 10}], d[{10, 0}]]]
```

Or...

```
d[c_, r_:10] := Region[Disk[c, r]];
q = {0, 10};
h = {5, -5};
RegionDifference[d[q + h, 5], RegionIntersection[d[q], d[q + 2 h]]]
```

Or....

```
d[c_, r_:10] := Region[Disk[c, r]]; q = {5, 5}; h = {5, -5};
RegionDifference[d[q, 5], RegionIntersection[d[q - h], d[q + h]]]
```

Pretty efficient!

Comment: I'd add `PlotPoints->50` to smooth the tips of the crescents

Comment: @Ruslan:  Yes... thanks.  I included `PlotPoints` in my trial runs, but wanted to keep the code minimal.